# Qt pyuic сгенерировал код который не запускается

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

через утилиту pyuic X.ui -o X.py был сгенерирован файл кода X.py

По факту не запускается питоном никак. Ожидалось, что хотя бы откроет графическое окно, чтобы потом привязать его к программе.

Писал через Qt DEsigner

вот текст файла.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'MM.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 541))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.frame)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 551))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuConvert = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuConvert.setObjectName("menuConvert")
        self.menuHelp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName("menuHelp")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts.setObjectName("actionConvert_Nokia_contacts")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menuConvert.addAction(self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuConvert.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuConvert.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Convert"))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionConvert_Nokia_contacts.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Convert Nokia contacts"))
```

Comment: Это весь код? То, что вы показали это сгенерированный класс по UI, а для запуска нужно создать `QApplication` и сам виджет. Пример: https://github.com/gil9red/alarm-clock/

Comment: Посмотрите инструкцию в ответе, если есть вопросы, могу уточнить

Comment: Посмотрел, спасибо. Я лютый новичок и не совсем понимаю в классах. Моя программа простой конвертер выполненный в  функциональном python. Qapp - где пишется, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: То, что вы новичек это и так видно :) но для таких новичков как вы и делают документации, статьи и т.п. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно закончить создание виджета.

Для этого:

- Сгенерированный файл назовите с постфиксом `_ui`: `mainwindow_ui.py`
- Создайте файл `mainwindow.py` и [в нем будет создан виджет](https://github.com/gil9red/alarm-clock/blob/master/mainwindow.py#L14):

  ```
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
  from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject     
  from mainwindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow


  class MainWindow(QMainWindow, QObject):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
          self.ui.setupUi(self)
  ```
- Теперь останется [создать объект приложения и виджета](https://github.com/gil9red/alarm-clock/blob/master/main.py#L28):

  ```
  from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication 

  app = QApplication([])

  mw = MainWindow()
  mw.show()

  app.exec()
  ```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmitriy.alekseev\Desktop\PY\Модульная программа\PyQT\mainwindow.py", line 4, in <module>
    class MainWindow(QMainWindow, QObject):
NameError: name 'QMainWindow' is not defined

Comment: Добавил импорт в ответе

Comment: А вот этот блок кода куда добавлять - в mainwindow.py или в mainwindow_ui.py? from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


app = QApplication([])

mw = MainWindow()
mw.show()

app.exec()

Comment: `mainwindow.py`, а лучше даже отдельный файл `main.py` завести, который соберет в себе все: https://github.com/gil9red/alarm-clock/blob/master/main.py

Comment: добавил как есть в mainwindow.py вывод Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmitriy.alekseev\Desktop\PY\Модульная программа\PyQT\mainwindow.py", line 13, in <module>
    app = QApplication([])
NameError: name 'QApplication' is not defined

Comment: нет импорта: `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication`

Comment: мда. почему то корректно установленный PyQt5 в Full комплектации не дает импорта. странно. Причину найти не могу

Comment: и что же пишет при `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication`?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)